# overflow is sending dropdown behind the parent div while using li, z-index is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

folks, I can't seem to figure out why overflow is breaking the code

so below code works fine in two conditions. 
a) if I remove overflow-x and overflow-y from .bs-exmple or 
b) if I remove ul and li

but I need both in my code, however with these css and ul and li being in code, the dropdown collapses behind the div. what am i missing

```
.bs-example {   border: 1px solid black;   overflow-y: scroll;   overflow-x: hidden;   min-height: 100px;   max-height: 250px; }
.bs-example .dropdown {   position: absolute;   z-index: 999; }

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="bs-example">
    <ul class="list-group ">
      <li class="list-group-item m-3 p-3">User 1
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Menu
                </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </li>

      <li class="list-group-item  m-3 p-3">User 2
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Menu2
                </button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

so you see, the image below shows the dropdown behind the div

[image]

I have codepen saved here
https://codepen.io/ozzie6935/pen/NEZBwW?editors=1100

any help is much appreciated

Comment: you want the dropdown to display in front of .bs-exmple?

Comment: I want dropdown to be in front of all elements

Comment: Use `js` to increase the height when dropdown is opened. I do not understand the need to restrict height and use `overflow` . Could you explain it?

Comment: The example above is a scaled down versrion of what I will have on the page. the container height is page appropriate and element within will populate with jquery when user scrolls down.
This is why height is restricted,
I need a solution to force dropdown out of the container, which works fine if i remove ul and li tags